# C# ASP.Net - Global.asax full of errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I am attempting to use the Global.asax file and it is failing miserably. Every line in the code has an error but the funny thing is that it does not matter how many lines, what the lines contain, etc have as it always reports an error. This makes me thing there is a configuration setting that isn't right but wouldn't know where to begin.

The project is a Web Site rather than a Web Application but I read up on Global.asax and it appears to be acceptable to use it in a Web Site. I have provided the code I am using to test that the Global.asax works in the project before writing the code needed for the project.

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

    static string _pagePath;

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // Code that runs on application startup
    _pagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Folder/Page.aspx");
    }

    // ...

    void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string path = Request.PhysicalPath;
    if (path == _pagePath)
    {
        Response.Write("Page viewed");
        Response.End();
    }
    }

</script>
```

I have also provided a list of example error messages that are cropping up

```
'Class' statement must end with a matching 
'End Class' 'If', 'ElseIf', 'Else', 'End If', 'Const', or 'Region' expected 
'Namespace' statement must end with a matching 'End Namespace' 
Statement cannot appear outside of a method body/multiline lambda.
```

Hopefully someone can pick out what I did wrong so I can use the Global.asax. Any help is widely appreciated!

Comment: Class, End Class, If, ElseIf, Else, End If, Namespace,End Namespace are VB.NET syntax, is your project a vb.net project ? you can't mix c# and VB.Net in the same project

Comment: Did you add the file manually? If so could you try getting it automatically generated instead and add the code you need?

Comment: It is a C# project and yes I did make it manually as it was not added automatically

Comment: Remove your global.asax file and add a new one. Be sure to remove the code file for it and not just the asax.

Comment: How would I re-add it? I could not add it automatically or manually. I had to add it as an existing file (Would not appear in the Add Items page)

Answer (score 0):

add Language="C#" property to the directive at the top of your global.asax. right click on the file, choose view markup, add the property and rebuild.

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="GLOBAL CLASS" Language="C#" %>
```